# How can I use command expansion on `\{\}` in `find -exec`?

Tags: bash, find, command-substitution

I would like to find some directories via

```
find /path/to/a/dir -type d  -links 2
```

and then for each pathname found by `find`,  assumed to be stored in variable `pathname`, I would like to

```
stow -d "$(dirname "$pathname")" -t /home/t/bin "$(basename "$pathname")"
```

How can I combine the above with `find -exec`, something similar to:

```
find /path/to/a/dir -type d  -links 2 -exec stow -d "$(dirname \{\})" -t /home/t/bin "$(basename \{\})" \;
```

I think it doesn't work because the shell performs the command substitutions before running `find`, and no pathname is found yet to replace `\{\}` in the command substitutions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrap it in a `sh -c` command

```
find /path/to/dir -type d -links 2 -exec sh -c 'stow -d "$(dirname "$1")" -t /home/t/bin "$(basename "$1")"' sh {} \;
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do you use `sh` instead of `bash` here?

Comment: `sh` is guaranteed to exist on any Unix system. On `linux`, `/bin/sh` is either a symlink to `/bin/bash` itself (eg. rhel, centos) or to something smaller and faster (`/bin/dash` on ubuntu and debian).